# How to find full path of corrupted files on BTRFS via journalctl?

Tags: btrfs

After running `btrfs scrub`, corrupted files can be detected. In order to determine the uncorrectable files, we may try reading every single file on the disk:

```
sudo find / -type f -exec cp -v {} /dev/null \; 2> corrupted-files.txt
```

Output of this command satisfies the need. However it takes hours to complete.

Arch Linux wiki suggests the following command to determine the corrupted files:

```
sudo journalctl --output cat | grep 'BTRFS .* i/o error' | sort | uniq
```

It fetches results fast. However, file paths are relative to their subvolume paths, thus invaluable for fixing the files from the backups:

```
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 69945753600 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 142920640, root 636, inode 172280, offset 238682112, length 4096, links 1 (path: home/aea/couchdb/couchdb/data/shards/60000000-7fffffff/client2.1533443496.couch)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70045958144 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143116352, root 422, inode 172296, offset 307662848, length 4096, links 1 (path: home/aea/couchdb/couchdb/data/shards/e0000000-ffffffff/client2.1533443496.couch)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70045958144 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143116352, root 636, inode 172296, offset 307662848, length 4096, links 1 (path: home/aea/couchdb/couchdb/data/shards/e0000000-ffffffff/client2.1533443496.couch)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70138376192 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143296856, root 423, inode 100548, offset 688631808, length 4096, links 1 (path: var/log/auth.log)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70138425344 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143296952, root 423, inode 100548, offset 688644096, length 4096, links 1 (path: var/log/auth.log)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70138441728 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143296984, root 423, inode 100548, offset 688648192, length 4096, links 1 (path: var/log/auth.log)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70138449920 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143297000, root 419, inode 818783, offset 95145984, length 4096, links 1 (path: var/log/daemon.log)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70138564608 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143297224, root 419, inode 818783, offset 95154176, length 4096, links 1 (path: var/log/daemon.log)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70138884096 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143297848, root 419, inode 818783, offset 95174656, length 4096, links 1 (path: var/log/daemon.log)
```

Is there a way to determine the subvolume path by using `sector XXXXXXX, root XXX, inode XXXXXXX, offset XXXXXXXX` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the `root XXX` value is the root ID of the subvolume. So the path of the corresponding subvolume can be determined by:

```
sudo btrfs sub list / | awk '$2 == 419 {print $9}'
var/lib/lxc/foo/rootfs
```

The useful script that makes the inner join is as follows:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

sub_list=/tmp/subvolume-list-of-root.txt

sudo btrfs sub list / > $sub_list

while read a; do
    root_id=$(echo $a | awk '{print $16}' | sed -r 's/,//')
    rel_path=$(echo $a | sed -r 's/.*path:\s(.+)\)/\1/g')
    subvol_path=$(cat $sub_list | awk '$2 == '"$root_id"' {print $9}')
    [[ -z $subvol_path ]] && subvol_path="????"
    echo "/$subvol_path/$rel_path"
done < <( cat << HELLO
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 69945753600 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 142920640, root 636, inode 172280, offset 238682112, length 4096, links 1 (path: home/aea/couchdb/couchdb/data/shards/60000000-7fffffff/client2.1533443496.couch)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70045958144 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143116352, root 422, inode 172296, offset 307662848, length 4096, links 1 (path: home/aea/couchdb/couchdb/data/shards/e0000000-ffffffff/client2.1533443496.couch)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70045958144 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143116352, root 636, inode 172296, offset 307662848, length 4096, links 1 (path: home/aea/couchdb/couchdb/data/shards/e0000000-ffffffff/client2.1533443496.couch)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70138376192 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143296856, root 423, inode 100548, offset 688631808, length 4096, links 1 (path: var/log/auth.log)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70138425344 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143296952, root 423, inode 100548, offset 688644096, length 4096, links 1 (path: var/log/auth.log)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70138441728 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143296984, root 423, inode 100548, offset 688648192, length 4096, links 1 (path: var/log/auth.log)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70138449920 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143297000, root 419, inode 818783, offset 95145984, length 4096, links 1 (path: var/log/daemon.log)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70138564608 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143297224, root 419, inode 818783, offset 95154176, length 4096, links 1 (path: var/log/daemon.log)
BTRFS warning (device dm-2): i/o error at logical 70138884096 on dev /dev/mapper/zeytin-root, sector 143297848, root 419, inode 818783, offset 95174656, length 4096, links 1 (path: var/log/daemon.log)
HELLO
)
```

Output:

```
./test.sh 

/????/home/aea/couchdb/couchdb/data/shards/60000000-7fffffff/client2.1533443496.couch
/var/lib/lxc/foo-couch2/rootfs/home/aea/couchdb/couchdb/data/shards/e0000000-ffffffff/client2.1533443496.couch
/????/home/aea/couchdb/couchdb/data/shards/e0000000-ffffffff/client2.1533443496.couch
/var/lib/lxc/foo-git/rootfs/var/log/auth.log
/var/lib/lxc/foo-git/rootfs/var/log/auth.log
/var/lib/lxc/foo-git/rootfs/var/log/auth.log
/var/lib/lxc/foo1/rootfs.bak/var/log/daemon.log
/var/lib/lxc/foo1/rootfs.bak/var/log/daemon.log
/var/lib/lxc/foo1/rootfs.bak/var/log/daemon.log
```

Thus the overall tool [get-corrupted-files.sh](https://github.com/ceremcem/monitor-btrfs-disk/blob/master/get-corrupted-files.sh) becomes:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

sub_list=/tmp/subvolume-list-of-root.txt

sudo btrfs sub list / > $sub_list

while read a; do
    root_id=$(echo $a | awk '{print $16}' | sed -r 's/,//')
    rel_path=$(echo $a | sed -r 's/.*path:\s(.+)\)/\1/g')
    subvol_path=$(cat $sub_list | awk '$2 == '"$root_id"' {print $9}')
    [[ -z $subvol_path ]] && subvol_path="????"
    echo "/$subvol_path/$rel_path"
done < <( sudo journalctl --output cat | grep 'BTRFS .* i/o error' | sort | uniq )
```